# How can i install this libraries?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, shared-libraries

[enter image description here][1]I have a problem with two libraries, one shows as this "C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\lib" and the other one is "C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\lib", they appear in red line like this picture, i've uninstalled and installed back Android Studio, i also copy the config from a "new flutter project" to my actual project, i also managed to upgrade the other libraries by using other tutorials, but i cant install this two libraries yet, on top of that, each time i press the play button on android studio to start installing my app to my phone, this error appears:

````
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.agorabuilder:native-full-sdk:3.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :agora_rtc_engine

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNXhP.png
````

Comment: Hi! it seems like you tried to add an error image but it was not added

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. clean project
2. rebuild project
3. file/ Invalidate caches / restart

Answer (score 0):

In the project-level build.gradle file of your android project add the following repository "maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }" It should look similar to this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        centre()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        centre()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution discussed here https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/325#issuecomment-844802327